# How to use image scan ecr command in a loop in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: loops, jenkins, sh, jenkins-groovy, string-interpolation

I wanted to create a jenkins pipeline that scans all the docker images in ecr..I have used the list-images command to list all the images and extracted ImageDigests in a ArrayList(arr).
But it wouldn't read the value of imageDigest when interpolating it in the sh image-scan command.

```
    arr.each{x  ->
       sh  '''aws ecr start-image-scan --repository-name databricks --image-id imageDigest="${x}" --region us-east-1   '''                                    
    }
```

output :
`aws ecr start-image-scan --repository-name databricks --image-id imageDigest= --region us-east-1`

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StartImageScan operation: `Invalid parameter at 'imageDigest' failed to satisfy constraint: 'must satisfy regular expression '[a-zA-Z0-9-_+.]+:[a-fA-F0-9]+''`

Comment: What is the value of ${x}? This command works perfectly for me. aws ecr start-image-scan --repository-name my-repo --image-id imageDigest=sha256:blahblah --profile my-profile

Comment: I had created a ArrayList of all the imageDigests I got from list-image command. x is the value of imageDigest while iterating through the ArrayList

Comment: I understood that is a array, but your command seem fine for me. Paste the command replacing the x variable for its value. You can truncate or change it but keep the format for an assessment

Comment: Actually I wanted to scan for each image in this array, as there are multiple images I want to scan..is that possible in a loop?